# My site appears zoomed in when opened on the phone

Tags: html, css, media, viewport, responsive

HEAD

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0,"/>
```

CSS

```
@media (max-width: 600px){
body{position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 420px;}
```

My site appears zoomed in when opened on the phone
[Screenshots is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M7W4b.jpg)

How can I fix?

Comment: Please share your site link, if possible.

Comment: http://helalpropolis.com/sayfa/hersey.php?w=salpin&s=kutuphane

Comment: @MuhammetSönmezalp everything ok when i view it. Are you sure you didn't double tap the mobile screen (in Chrome emulator) ?

Comment: I don't. It is do when the page loads

Comment: I am zoom out later and refresh rezoom in

Comment: Did you look at the phone?

Comment: Can you share your phone resolution?

Comment: @Aman i think it's the same as the Nexus 5x in Chrome emulator.

Comment: Resolution: 720 x 1280

Comment: Phone width 720px

Comment: Why does not seem fully?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting the `body`'s width to be wider than the phone's screen (since your viewport tag causes "px" units to not be 1:1 so 1 pixel on the phone doesn't correspond to 1 px unit). You should either use relative values for your `body` style

```
@media (max-width: 600px){
    body{
        position: absolute; 
        top: 0; 
        left: 0; 
        width: 100vw;
        max-width: 420px;
    }
}
```

or create an extra `@media` query for devices narrower than 420px like this:

```
@media (min-width: 420px) and (max-width: 600px){
    body{
        position: absolute; 
        top: 0; 
        left: 0; 
        width: 420px;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 420px){
    body{
        position: absolute; 
        top: 0; 
        left: 0; 
        right: 0;
    }
}
```

Edit:

Here's another approach with a dynamic viewport tag:

```
<meta id="viewport" name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
<script>
window.onload = function() {
    if(screen.width < 420){
        var viewport = document.getElementById('viewport');
        viewport.setAttribute('content', 'width=420, initial-scale=1');
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: It will be very difficult
My all content is for 420px

Comment: Then you could change your viewport tag to `<meta name="viewport" content="width=420, initial-scale=1.0">` I guess. You should try to make your content work on any width in the future if you want your site to look good on all screens.

Comment: I added an approach with a dynamic viewport tag to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

`initial-scale=1.0` tells the browser to set the zoom level to normal (i.e. not zoomed in or out). You only need `width=1000`:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=1000">
```

Comment: That is not what OP's asking for.

Comment: This causes a sub-par and also inconsistent mobile experience since the text might appear too small to read depending on screen size. `width=device-width` aims to make text readable on any screen.